# C# filtering json results from restclient

Tags: c#, json

I am completely new to C# and have zero background in the language.
The only programming language I am an expert in is SQL.

My situation:
I have a an API url from a website my company uses to monitor product levels in tanks.
The API returns a json list of the tanks (location, tank id, tank size, current level, etc.).
My goal is to create a windows form application with an input field.
The user types the name of the location, clicks a button, and sees the information for any tanks at that location.

What I have tried:

What I have done so far:
Again, I have zero knowledge of programming so do not be critical if I have done things in very unusual/inefficient ways.
I have managed to create a windows form that has a button and text box.
When the button is clicked, the text box is populated with all of the tank data from the API.
I can't figure out how to filter the data that has been returned.
My current code is below...

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using static APIform.Form1;

namespace APIform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://{{my tank monitor website}}/admin/data_feed_configs/140.json");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("auth-token", "{{my token}}");
            request.AddHeader("auth-email", "{{my authorization email}}");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "{{my auth code}}");
            request.AddHeader("Cookie", "{{cookies}}");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            var data = response.Content;
            JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(data);

            textBox1.Text = jsonArray.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I have added a model class TankClass that resembles the text returned from the request.

```
public class TankClass
{
    public string location_name { get; set; }
    public string owner_name { get; set; }
    public string tank_id { get; set; }
    public string tank_name { get; set; }
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    public int tank_size { get; set; }
    public string sensor_value { get; set; }
    public string reading_inches { get; set; }
    public string reading_volume { get; set; }
    public string available_capacity { get; set; }
    public int fill_percentage { get; set; }
    public string fill_status { get; set; }
    public string alert_status { get; set; }
    public int days_to_empty { get; set; }
    public string battery_level { get; set; }
    public string product_sku { get; set; }
    public string reading_time { get; set; }
    public string division { get; set; }
}
```

Everything I try to deserialize/filter the results does not seem to be working.
What do I need to add into the code to make this work?
I have a second text box (textbox2) on the form.
This is where the user will enter "Warehouse 1" for example.
When they then hit the button, I would like only tanks at Warehouse 1 to show in the textbox1 field.

With my current code, this is a sample of what shows in the textbox1 field when clicking the button:

```
[
  {
    "location_name": "Warehouse 1",
    "owner_name": "ABC Oil, Inc.",
    "tank_id": "W00813862",
    "tank_name": "Dow - Desitherm (TEG) Tank #M-20-065",
    "product_name": "Dow - Desitherm (TEG)",
    "tank_size": 2005.0,
    "sensor_value": "2.379",
    "reading_inches": "29.6",
    "reading_volume": "908.2",
    "available_capacity": "1096.8",
    "fill_percentage": 45,
    "fill_status": "COULD",
    "alert_status": "",
    "days_to_empty": 124.4,
    "battery_level": "6.1",
    "product_sku": "",
    "reading_time": "2020-09-16T10:55:35-04:00",
    "division": "1024"
  },
  {
    "location_name": "Warehouse 2",
    "owner_name": "ABC Oil, Inc.",
    "tank_id": "Z057101",
    "tank_name": "OSI 84  - Diesel Exhaust Fluid (DEF)",
    "product_name": "Diesel Exhaust Fluid (DEF)",
    "tank_size": 8806.0,
    "sensor_value": "2554.0 | 3263.0",
    "reading_inches": "76.3",
    "reading_volume": "4868.8",
    "available_capacity": "3937.2",
    "fill_percentage": 55,
    "fill_status": "GOOD",
    "alert_status": "",
    "days_to_empty": 14.5,
    "battery_level": "-",
    "product_sku": "",
    "reading_time": "2020-09-16T10:59:00-04:00",
    "division": ""
  },
.
.
.
]
```

**My Program.cs tab:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using RestSharp;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using static APIform.Form1;

namespace APIform
{
    public class TankClass
    {
        public string location_name { get; set; }
        public string owner_name { get; set; }
        public string tank_id { get; set; }
        public string tank_name { get; set; }
        public string product_name { get; set; }
        public double tank_size { get; set; }
        public string sensor_value { get; set; }
        public string reading_inches { get; set; }
        public string reading_volume { get; set; }
        public string available_capacity { get; set; }
        public int fill_percentage { get; set; }
        public string fill_status { get; set; }
        public string alert_status { get; set; }
        public double days_to_empty { get; set; }
        public string battery_level { get; set; }
        public string product_sku { get; set; }
        public DateTime reading_time { get; set; }
        public string division { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the controller as well and the form

Comment: Also a problem with the `class` is that `tank_size` and `days_to_empty` need to be `double` not `int`, `reading_time` could be changed `DateTime`

Comment: Thanks @janzen

The first bit of code I posted above is what is in my Form1.cs tab.  
I will add in what is on my Program.cs tab.

Again, I've never looked at Visual Studio or C# before two days ago so forgive my ignorance and not understanding a lot of the terminology.
I don't see any "controllers" in my project.

Comment: You should deserialise the JSON into a list containing instances of your tank object. i.e. `List<TankClass>` - this will be more useful than a JArray. Then you can filter the list with linq queries. See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm . e.g. `List<TankClass> tanks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TankClass>>(data);`

Comment: Ignore what I said about Controllers, I was thinking this was a web app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class just change `tank_size` and `days_to_empty` to a `double` and `reading_time` to `DateTime`.

Then `Deserialize` into a `List<TankClass>`

```
var listOfTanks = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TankClass>>(data);
```

Then with the form data, you can use `Linq` to filter the results:

```
var returnValues = listOfTanks.Where(x => x.location_name == TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I feel like we're inching closer to a solution but it still doesn't seem to be complete.

I added in the two lines of code you suggested, but then how do I display the results?
I tried using `StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(); foreach (var item in returnValues) { b.Append(item); b.AppendLine(); } string output = b.ToString();`   and then setting textBox2.Text = output.  If I pick a location with 6 tanks, I get six lines of code returned but they all just show "APIform.TankClass".

Comment: Just create `string` variables, loop through the list `returnValues`. Set each item in `returnValues` to its corresponding `string` variable that was created

Comment: Or set `string results = " ";` then `foreach (var item in returnValues) { string values = item.location_name + " " + item.owner_name ...; results+= "\n" + values; }`
Finally `TextBox2.Text = results;`

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you so much for helping me out.  I know it wasn't very difficult but it was driving a C# noob like me crazy.

Comment: Glad to help! Sorry it took me a while to respond to the comment, I was misunderstanding what you said so my bad. If this answer works then Accept it please!